# Is there a way to adapt diff_drive_controller for four wheel robot?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I have a two wheeled robot that works fine. I want to remake it to be four wheeled one. I know that there is four_wheel_steering_controller and ackerman_controller but I want to try this with diff_drive controller. For unknown for know reason after adapting urdf and control.yaml files with reference to husky robot (as far as I understand, they managed to make it work the way I want it to work) my robot can move but can't turn. So at some point it will hit the wall or any other obstacle. Appreciate any hints.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410898/is-there-a-way-to-adapt-diff_drive_controller-for-four-wheel-robot?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-12-28**:
Is failure in simulation or with a real robot?

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-12-29**:
In simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In simulation, I have seen this problem caused by the amount of friction between the wheels and the ground. You need to check the values for both the forward direction and the perpendicular direction (i.e. the robot's y-axis.) The values can't be too small and they can't be too large.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2023-01-26**:
Thank you for help. It work's now.